# Get the current location of user on background

Tags: android, sockets, push-notification, android-service, android-location

Just have question about best approach to use, I need to send query from my device to other device to get the current location, so I think I have two choices.
The first is using sockets.
Or push notification.

The idea is to to send query to start service to get the current location of the user.
Also using services, not sure if it is the best choice.
the user I will get his location I don't want him to see anything, all work will done on background.

thank you.

Comment: Basically you have two phones and one phone wants the location of another phone?

Comment: yes exactly, and the second phone will do the work on background

Comment: Well, theoretically,.... one way of doing it would be to use GCM, something like a chat app for base, except instead of creating a notification when the user receives a message from the GCM server it will start a AsyncTask to get location then on postExecute will send the location of the phone back using Upstream Message/ just send your server if you don't want the data to pass through the server.

Comment: thank you @j4rey89 thats what I want to know :) thanks for the quick replay

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a webservice which your device will continually ping to and update his lat, long on server and then another service from where other device will get the location of first device.

Answer (score 0):

According to me service is best option for this and if you need to get location with specific time duration then you can use service with alarm manager.

Comment: thanks for the quick replay, the time to get the location is not fixed so the alarm manager is not the best choice. but like Whatsapp for example do: send message and the other user get notified, but for my case I want just start the service  to get the location.